# Cant access my laravel api from postman but can access my web route

Tags: laravel, api

Good day techies, i had to work on a project, so i did php artisan route:list which i see all the route in the api route and which they all came out in this pattern

> prepcrm.test        | GET|HEAD                               | v1/client/cycles                                               | v1::client.tutor-cycles                                | App\Http\Controllers\V1\Client\ClientClassController@getCycleRecords                 | api,client,auth

which the domain is `prepcrm.test`, so i created a virtual host in that domain name, and eveyry time I make a request from postman, the response I get back is "The requested URL was not found on this server." so i wrote a small block of code to just output hello world in my api route and web route and try to access it using postman, the web route request works fine but the api route is "exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"..
have been on this for some days now, trying to make things work but to no futile..
What could have been done to not make the api route not working...
Your contribution goes a long way.
Thanks

Comment: umm, just curious, what http method did you use on postman? also, are you using [tag:laravel-passport]?

Comment: Do you have a valid bearer token for that api ?

Comment: its a get method and its not laravel-passport, its jwt....the route am requesting is not protected route

Comment: This sounds like your JWT authentication is not working so if you can share some more of the code that is meant to do that work (or if you are using a 3rd party library, what that is and how you are using it) then we might be able to help

Comment: The route you copy pasted is protected by auth middleware

Comment: this is what is in my congig/auth.php   'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'tutor' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'tutors',
        ],
        'client' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'clients',
        ],
    ],

Comment: and this 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'clients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Client::class,
        ],

        'tutors' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Tutor::class,
        ],
    ],

Comment: and the jwt package is  tymon/jwt-auth

Comment: For your API I think you need to use middleware `auth:clients` if you're authenticating clients on that route (instead of just `auth`)

Comment: i think i found the glitches, the api routes was configured in this way Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1/crm', 'as'=>'v1::crm.', 'namespace' => 'V1', 'domain' => config('app.api-domain')], base_path('routes/api/v1/crm.php')); and in my config file its 'api-domain' => env('API_DOMAIN', 'prepcrm.test'), so when i removed the domain from the route, it works fine..but i would still like to continue with this pattern..how can i access it postman

Comment: i sorted it out..it was because i was not running my laravel on port 80

Answer (score 0):

On your request headers you should add

```
Accept => application/json
```

And sometimes maybe Content-type:

```
Content-Type => application/json
```

[Example from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fReQH.png)

Comment: i sorted it out..it was because i was not running my laravel on port 80

Comment: Glad you fixed but NotFoundException wouldn't shown if you had wrong port so its kinda wierd. Have a nice day

Comment: before that i had to set my virtual host to the env url and also move the .htaccess to public folder